# App Link when shared on Facebook through android/Ios app

Tags: php, android, facebook, facebook-share, applinks

Im currently implementing share functionality in my Android/IOS app but encounter some issues providing a correct link for the facebook scraper.

So from my perspective there are 2 options:

1. Use facebook Hosting for App-link
2. Use a custom redirect php on own website

The problem with app links created from facebook is that they dont include thumbnais in the post shared.. Is it possible to add og:tags to facebook app links? I guess not, but have to ask. That would solve my problem.

However using a custom php to redirect users to the app store/play store depending on platform, creates another problem.

Facebook scrapes images from the final url, in this case the app-store/playstore site of the app.. While scraping correctly the image from the play store, it has problems with the image from the app store, too big it gets cut off in the facebook post. (snapchat example below)

Are there any better alternatives?

Thanks in advance for any help, working on this some days now, any help is appreciated.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9Z1a.png)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a better alternative. [Branch](http://branch.io) allows for custom redirect to the app store or to another custom fallback. It handles edge case from every device and coming from every app. Branch links will allow you to pass OG tags that should provide those thumbnails. Here's an example Branch link under the hood:

```
tags: [ 'tag1', 'tag2' ],
channel: 'facebook',
feature: 'dashboard',
stage: 'new user',
alias: 'myalias',
data: {
    mydata: 'something',
    foo: 'bar',
    '$desktop_url': 'http://myappwebsite.com',
    '$ios_url': 'http://myappwebsite.com/ios',
    '$android_url': 'http://myappwebsite.com/android',
    '$og_app_id': '12345',
    '$og_title': 'My App',
    '$og_description': 'My app\'s description.',
    '$og_image_url': 'http://myappwebsite.com/image.png'
}
```

You can see how to configure links [here](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/configuring-links/guide/). This deep linking service that you are looking for is completely **free** at Branch.